# Socket.IO on client side

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am creating a nodejs+express+socket.io server.

Also I created a scaffold via yeoman for my frontend app.

The socket.io server is on port 3000 and my yeoman scaffold http server on 9000.

I have managed to retrieve the socket.io.js from the socket.io server using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

However im having this error:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1425392110184-42 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is the socket.io.js polling on port 9000?
Moreover, how can I change this so that it'll poll on 3000 instead?

Comment: remove `http://localhost:3000` from the script `src`

Comment: I highly doubt that's not the problem. If I remove that then I cannot fetch the client script from the socket.io server.

Comment: You have a client side issue. Can you create your own socket connection with: `var socket = new io.Socket();  socket.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');`

Comment: @Aleksander I have figured it out already. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket.io client takes an option URL argument.  If not specified, it will connect using the *current document origin*.  This means if the HTML document's URL is `http://localhost:9000`, then it will connect to `http://localhost:9000`.  Specify it when you connect:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

Instead of

```
var socket = io();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it by passing the url of the socket.io as parameter to the `io()` function.

`var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');`